# Loading JDBC driver without Class.forName

Tags: java, jdbc

The [Oracle JDBC tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html) says

> In previous versions of JDBC, to obtain a connection, you first had to
> initialize  your JDBC driver by calling the method Class.forName. This
> methods required an  object of type java.sql.Driver. Each JDBC driver
> contains  one or more classes that implements the interface
> java.sql.Driver.  The drivers for Java DB are
> org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver and
> org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver,  and the one for MySQL Connector/J
> is com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.  See the documentation of your DBMS driver
> to obtain the  name of the class that implements the interface
> java.sql.Driver.
>
> Any JDBC 4.0 drivers that are found in your  class path are automatically loaded.  (However, you must manually load any drivers
> prior to JDBC 4.0  with the method Class.forName.)

But when I remove `Class.forName` it gives an error *No Driver found*. I am using `ojdbc14` driver. How do we implement connection without `Class.forName`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look closely at the JDBC version. The article says that it's introduced in JDBC 4.0 (Java 1.6).

However, `ojdbc14` is a JDBC 3.0 (Java 1.5) driver.

Comment: Is ojdbc6 Version 4.0? If not please name a few JDBC 4.0 drivers.

Comment: Just read JDBC driver vendor's own documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/jdbcvers.htm#BCFFIFAD

Comment: @BalusC-how can we add jar in classpath?

Comment: Depends on type of application and how it's executed. It's after all just the same way as you already did for `ojdbc14`.

Comment: For ojdbc14 i copied the jar to jdk1.6.0_21\jre\lib\ext and it worked.

Comment: Uh oh, that'll indeed work, but that's **definitely not** the right way :) But that's a completely different question/matter. Don't be ashamed, misunderstanding the "classpath" is a quite common starter's mistake. Again, the right location depends on type of application and how it's executed.